# Visualization/activization maximization for regression neural net?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, deep-learning

Suppose we have a neural net that maps an image to a single scalar value (linear activation). What methods exist to visualize the structure of a neural network given an output? Can you use activation maximization?

Comment: What do you mean by "visualizing the structure of the neural network given an output"?

Comment: Thanks! Activation maximization refers to a technique that maximizes the activation of hidden units given a desired output class (I think it's trained through gradient ascent). These weights can then be visualized. I was wondering if there exist related/similar techniques for a regression problem. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you want rather than visualizing  the structure of a network (which sounds more like visualizing its architecture) is to *visualize the features represented by individual units*. As far as I know, this is done by optimizing the network *input* to maximize the activation of a unit (instead of maximizing an activation given an *output*). Alternatively you can visualize it by looking up images from your training set which maximize the unit activation. In this setup, it does not matter if your network is doing regression or classification, because you are only maximizing a unit inside the network.

I recommend reading the article [Feature Visualization](https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/) containing great explanations on this topic.

Comment: On Keras blog there is an [article](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html) with code on this.

Answer (score 2):

If your model is easily implementable in Keras, then you can use [quiver](https://github.com/keplr-io/quiver) engine to visualize activities of neurons given inputs.

It looks something like this

[image]

If you want to set it up you could look at [this example](https://github.com/lambdaofgod/examples-counterexamples/blob/master/notebooks/neural_nets/Keras%20CNN%20visualization%20with%20Quiver.ipynb).